# Batch file calling vbs wont run from Task scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file scheduled in task scheduler. If I run this batch file manually from CMD, It will do all the work well and taking about 20 mins. But if I schedule it in task scheduler, it finishes immediately when starting to run and shows the result is "successfully finished...." (VBS didnt run...) This batch file will call up 2 vbs scripts to run. I am not sure if there is something wrong with task scheduler or just batch file gets wrong code in there.

```
 @echo off

set logfile=c:\temp\Shop_Floor_Schedule.%TIME:~0,2%.log

echo %date% %time% > %logfile%

cscript  "c:\work\scripts\Export.vbs" >> %logfile% 2>&1

cscript  "c:\work\scripts\Schedule.vbs" >> %logfile% 2>&1

echo "batch complete" >> %logfile%
```

I got error massages in log file

```
Fri 06/19/2015 10:00:00.13 
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

starting Excel
opening workbook
c:\work\scripts\Export.vbs(30, 1) Microsoft Excel: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\ntfs3\scripts\PRODUCTION.xls'. There are several possible reasons:

 The file name or path does not exist.
 The file is being used by another program.
 The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
```

I only get this message from task scheduler, but if run it from cmd manually, everything just well.

Comment: Are you sure the vbscripts are not actually running? They are likely running but failing for some reason...like running under a different user account in the scheduled job.

Comment: Yes, I am sure vbs is not running. I run it with domain admin permissions. Whe I run it manually, It will take 100% cup and 85% of ram, but If i run it from task scheduler, all system resources stay idle....

Comment: Does it write out your date and time and "batch complete" messages to the log file?

Comment: Is anything written to `%logfile%` from the vbscript lines?

Comment: If you're not getting the log file, then the problem is probably somewhere in the Scheduled Task setup.  If it is creating the log file, then you should see the output of the VB scripts and any errors they are outputting.

Comment: Yes, I am getting log file and it says one of excel file can not be accessed. but if i run this manually from cmd, there is no error at all, all run very well

Comment: Are the the vbscripts accessing files on a mapped drive? The mapped drive won't be accessible to the scheduled task unless you map it in your batch file.

Comment: no, it is not mapped drive, access it directly on a network share like \\server\data with domain admin permissions

Comment: If it's saying the Excel file cannot be accessed, then you likely have a permissions problem. What is the exact error message?

Comment: Does the task store the user's credentials?

Comment: I updated the post for error message

Comment: Download Process Monitor to see exactly what error is being returned by the file system.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: ...and probably post the code in the VBScript leading up to and including that line.  You can remove any processing code--just show loops and file opens, etc.

Comment: Under what account is the scheduled task running?

Comment: Try executing cscript  "c:\work\scripts\Initialize.vbs" - Use this vbscript to execute the processes using Shell run or shell exec to fire off the other commands. See if the results process the same and just work on your logging instead of using stdout redirects. - https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/41f111c0-e1fb-4908-b31f-2e3b37a36910

Answer (score 0):

Get out of the habit of logging using wscript.echo & stdOut vbscript outputs... its a terrible practice and reduces your ability to include logic to work around problems like this.

I would recommend that fix for method. Instead of using >> %log% 2>&1... Use a argument to your vbscripts for the logfile. It's a simple solution. Just point your scheduled task at this vbscript.. it should fix your issues for this batch file issue.

```
const forreading = 1, forwriting = 2, forappending, 8
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set shell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
logfile = "C:\temp\Shop_Floor_Schedule" & Hour(now()) & ".Log"

' Start Export.Vbs
'============================================================    
Call WriteLog("Starting Export VBScript")
Shell.run "cmd /c cscript  c:\work\scripts\Export.vbs >> """ & logfile & """ 2>&1"


' Start Schedule.vbs
'========================================
Call WriteLog("Starting Schedule VBScript")
Shell.run "cmd /c cscript  c:\work\scripts\Schedule.vbs >> """ & logfile & """ 2>&1"

'Terminate Objects and exit script
'============================================================
Call WriteLog("Terminating Script")
Set objShell = Nothing
Set fso = nothing

Sub WriteLog(strMessage)
    set logf = fso.OpenTextFile(logfile, forappending, true)
    strTime = Hour(Now()) & ":" & Minute(Now())
    logf.writeline = Date() & " - " & strTime & "   " & strMessage
    logf.close
    set logf = nothing
end sub
```